# Perl testing fake hash reference return

Tags: perl, unit-testing

I have a function that returns a Hash reference. The particular function is talking to a resource that has a high latency reply and is run multiple times. Depending on how many times it is called - running or testing the program make take minutes.

What I would like to do is have a test Mock the return of the function and but otherwise run the program as normal.

I'm new to the idea of Perl testing or any code testing really so appreciate guidance on how this is achieved.

function could be anything really.

```
sub my_func {
    my $data;
    .... get_data_from_high_latency_resource...

    return $data;
 }
```

$data being a hash reference in this case but I imagine it I was asking this question about a scalar or array it would not make a difference.

Comment: can you add the function to your question?

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar issue at work this morning; I had a bug in code that needed fixed, but the code was resistant to unit testing as it was hard coded to make a POST request as part of the operation. I used the [Sub::Override](http://search.cpan.org/~ovid/Sub-Override-0.09/lib/Sub/Override.pm) module to stub out the "make_http_request" function and had my stub return a Data::Dumper'd version of the parameters. Output that in my test and the bug was exposed.

The documentation for the module is straightforward but it pretty much goes like this:

```
my $object_under_test = My::Object->new(); # This has a method called run_me

my $override = Sub::Override->new( My::Object::run_me => sub { return 'I have run' } );

my $result = $object_under_test->run_me();
# $result now contains "I have run"
```